# BalmUI in vue3 vite project. How to change dialog's width

Tags: vuejs3, balmui

I try to use a BalmUI ui-dialog component and I want to change its max-width.
I use this style in the page where I use the component but it seems effectless.

```
<style lang="scss" >
@use '@material/dialog' with ($min-width: 280px,
  $max-width: 1560px,
);
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the `max-width` of a BalmUI `ui-dialog` component in a Vue 3 Vite project, you'll want to directly style the dialog element using CSS.

```
<template>
  <ui-dialog class="custom-dialog">
  <!-- Dialog content here -->
  </ui-dialog>
</template>

<style scoped>
.custom-dialog .mdc-dialog__surface {
 max-width: 1560px !important; /* Adjust the max-width as needed */
}
</style>
```

In this example, the `.custom-dialog` class is applied to the `ui-dialog` component. Within the scoped CSS, you target the `.md-dialog` class (which is the dialog content container within BalmUI), and set the `max-width` property to your desired value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does'nt work as expected. First I had to use .mdc-dialog__content instead of .md-dialog. Otherwise I can choose a width less than 560px but when I try more, I am limited by .mdc-dialog_surface. I can force it in the inspect tool of the browser but I cannot manage to change it using the style.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I feel very sorry bu it is a bit late now as I switched to ElementPlus. But for the information of other people, except the name of classes what matters the most in you answer. Is it the "!important" in the max-width?

Comment: Eventually I gave it a try. It doesn't change any thing: setting width to .mdc-dialog__container, .mdc-dialog_surface and .mdc-dialog_content (the three of them altogether) doesn't permit to go above 560px but only to diminish the width. The limitation is the $max-width but I don't know how to change it .